# How to run a Matlab file with calling a c++ dll

Tags: c++, matlab

I am trying to run the Matlab code from this link : (Please refer to the download section at bottom)
http://cvn.ecp.fr/personnel/iasonas/sketch.html

After I downloaded the source code, I follow the step in the readme.pdf

I am running the demo1 by Matlab R2014a

1.) Place the root folder and all of its subfolders in the Matlab path.

besides,

I enter into **filtering** subfolder , then execute command

```
mex iir_gauss.cpp
```

After it show **MEX completed successfully.** I try to compile kdtree.cc in kdtree/src subfolder.

But fails:

[image]

Error Message are : *c:\users\user\desktop\ps_primal_sketch\ps_primal_sketch\kdtree\src\kdtree_common.h(20) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open
include file: '/Applications/MATLAB6p5p1/extern/include/mex.h': No such file or directory*

Without compile the file, I can't run demo1, due to fail to call one of the function (kdtree).

Can anyone teach me how to execute the file (demo1) ? I saw there is a kdtree.dll in kdtree\mex\win subfolder, do I need to compile the kdtree.cc file again ? Please teach me in details, because I am a beginner of Matlab, thanks.

Comment: did you do `mex -setup` first?

Comment: If you are running Matlab R2014a, how come the error message refers folder `MATLAB6p5p1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved the puzzle...

Replace line 20 in file `kdtree_common.h` with `#include "mex.h"`

---

The problem relies in the source code you have downloaded.

Look at the beginning of `kdtree_common.h`.
It looks as follows:

```
// Guy Shechter
// June 2004
// 
// Uncomment one of these includes depending on your architecture.
// Your installation location may vary.
//
//
// For Linux use this line:
//
//#include "/usr/local/matlab/extern/include/mex.h"
//
//
// For Windows systems use this line:
//
//#include "c:\matlab6p1\extern\include\mex.h"
//
//
// For Mac Os X systems use this line :
//
#include "/Applications/MATLAB6p5p1/extern/include/mex.h"
//
//
```

As you can see, the include path refers to `"/Applications/MATLAB6p5p1/extern/include/mex.h"`

The comment says "`For Mac Os X systems use this line :`"

Since you are using Windows OS you supposed to put it in comment, and remove `#include "c:\matlab6p1\extern\include\mex.h"` from comment.

It's not going to work, because it refers to an older version of Matlab.

You don't need to use the full path, just replace it with:

```
#include "mex.h"
```